# How to create "public string array" from parameter as array?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, arraylist, parameters

I have this code:

```
public static void SendDataToES(String startTimestamp, String startDate, String bid_x, String ask_x)
{
    var tem_ehm = new Pre_Market
    {
        timestamp = startTimestamp,
        date = startDate,
        bid = bid_x,
        ask = ask_x
    };
}

class Pre_Market
{
    public string x_ric { get; set; }
    public string ask { get; set; }
    public string bid { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

.

But in the future, it will have parameters as Array.

public static void SendDataToES(String startTimestamp, String startDate, String bid_x, String ask_x, **IList nameABC, String[] getABCs**)

which nameABC[] has value A,B,C and getABC[] has value 1,2,3 so I would like to create in class Pre_Market as Array

```
public string[] A { get; set;}
public string[] B { get; set;}
public string[] C { get; set;}
```

Not sure below is working fine ?

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < nameABC.Count(); i++ )
{
  public string[] nameABC[i] { get; set; }
}
```

so that the below is available ?

```
var tem_ehm = new Pre_Market
{
    timestamp = startTimestamp,
    date = startDate,
    bid = bid_x,
    ask = ask_x,
    A = getABC[0],
    B = getABC[1],
    C = getABC[2]
};
```

**Updated ! Below is working fine on my side.**

```
var temp_ehm = new Pre_Market
{
    timestamp = startTimestamp,
    date = startDate,
    fids = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
};

for (int i = 0; i < nameFIDs.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    temp_ehm.fids.Add(nameFIDs[i], get_FIDs[i]);
}
```

"fids in temp_ehm can be added" that’s news to me!

Comment: You could build up your object structure in JSON ( building a string is easy ), and then use a JSON deserializer (install NewtonSoft.JSON via NuGet) to convert it to an object. and in that case you can use anonymos object instead of the defined `Pre_Market` class

Comment: I´m not sure I understood what you ment. You want your `Pre_Market`-class to also have an `A`, a `B` and a `C`-property? And thiose properties should be set within `getABC`? I´m not sure what this `getABC` should do or what it should return.

Comment: are you trying to "generate" a `public string[]` properties named "nameABC[0]", "nameABC[1]", "nameABC[2]" in `Pre_Market` class? If so, you definitely need to learn more about C#. You can't generate properties in defined classes. Actualy you can, using some sort of reflections and/or dynamics magic, but this is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with using an anonymous class instead of `Pre_Market`, then You can build up your object structure in JSON ( building a string is easy ), and then use a JSON deserializer (`install NewtonSoft.JSON via NuGet`) to convert it to an object

Here how you may want to generate your JSON string

```
string jsonStr = "{ timestamp = \"" + startTimestamp + "\"," +
    "date = \"" + startDate + "\"," +
    "bid = \"" + bid_x + "\"," +
    "ask = \"" + ask_x + "\"";

for ( int i = 0 ; i < nameABC.Count(); i++ )
{
  jsonStr  += "," + nameABC[i] + " = \"" + getABCs[i] + "\""
}

jsonStr += "}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I like this idea but I tried your idea and then face an issue without class Pre_Check which need to use for POST API to Elasticsearch about type

Comment: @SnowprincezCoffee
Can you please upvote it, as it solves the question of adding A, B..properties

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a dictionary.

```
public static void SendDataToES(String startTimestamp, String startDate, String bid_x, String ask_x, IList<string> nameABC, string[] getABCs)
{
    var tem_ehm = new Pre_Market
    {
        timestamp = startTimestamp,
        date = startDate,
        bid = bid_x,
        ask = ask_x,
        ABCs = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    };
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string name in nameABCs)
        tem_ehm.Add(name, getABCs[i++];

    // access the ABCs like so:
    string A = tem_ehm.ABCs["A"];
    string B = tem_ehm.ABCs["B"];
    string C = tem_ehm.ABCs["C"];
}

class Pre_Market
{
    public string x_ric { get; set; }
    public string ask { get; set; }
    public string bid { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ABCs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. It's working fine on my side.